# The PHP unset doesn't clear the reference completely

Tags: php, static, unset

I have a simple class and assign its instance to its static variable. When I unset the instance, not sure why it doesn't actual release the memory.

```
class Foo {
    public static $app;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$app = $this;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;

unset($foo);

var_dump($foo);

var_dump(Foo::$app);
```

Result:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $foo in /var/www/index.php on line 16
NULL object(Foo)#1 (0) { }
```

Obviously, the static $app point to the itself instance, we have unset the instance but doesn't really clean the memory for this variable. Why did it happen? Are the instance of the $app and the $foo different ones?

Comment: Start with a simpler example: `$a = "something"; $b = $a; unset($a); echo $b; echo $a;` what do you think will happen?

Comment: Hi @qrsngky The sample you provided and my are different. Obviously, $a and $b in your case are pointing to different memory address. Let change a bit to see they are different. ```$a = "something"; $b = $a; $a = "other"; echo $b; echo $a;```
But in my case, the $app and the $foo point to the same memory address, if you change $foo->test = 1; then the $app will have the test property with value 1.

Comment: Try out this one `$a = new stdClass(); $b = $a; $a->test = 1; unset($a); var_dump($b); var_dump($a);`  In the end, even though $a no longer refers to anything, $b is still pointing to a valid object (i.e. not destroyed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only unset a reference to an object of class `Foo`, and that object will get garbage-collected next time garbage collector runs.

Classes, once loaded, live in the memory until request is terminated, and so will their static properties. If they hold a pointer to an object, that object won't be garbage-collected. If you want to garbage-collect `Foo::$app`, you'll need to unset it too.

Answer (score 3):

- `$foo` and `Foo::$app` point to the same object as you desire. Any changes in terms of object properties will reflect either way if you do it.
- This is because they point to the same copy in the memory as expected. However, PHP maintains a `refcount` indicating how many references to that memory location is present.
- So, when you use `unset($foo);`, it doesn't garbage collect that memory location(and the value inside it), but rather just decreases the `refcount` of it. This can be proved using [`debug_zval_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) and PHP achieves the refcount maintenance using *copy on write* mechanism as mentioned in the linked doc.
- Hence, unsetting `$foo` doesn't destroy the object itself but rather just the `refcount` and removes the variable from memory since the object still holds other references.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php 

class Foo {
    public static $app;
    public function __construct() {
        self::$app = $this;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;

var_dump($foo === Foo::$app);

debug_zval_dump(Foo::$app);

$foo = 90;// variable modified, copy on write mechanism done internally for Foo::$app, refcount modified

debug_zval_dump(Foo::$app);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/982d9)